# Is $b=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2\\-1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ in the null space of $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&2\\3&4\\5&6\end{smallmatrix}\right)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Is vector $\mathrm b = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$ in the null space of $\mathrm A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\ 5 & 6\end{pmatrix}$?

My solution:

I took matrix A and put it in reduced echelon form. I calculated this to be:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & | & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & | & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & | & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

So $x_1= 0$ and $x_2 = 0$. But from here I am not sure how to answer the question

Comment: You're welcome! You can now look at the code that I used to format it like this so you can do it yourself next time!

Comment: perfect thanks for the help   do you know how to help me with this question?

Comment: Well, for $b$ to be in the null space you need to have $Ab = 0$, so why don't you check that?

Comment: so just multiply the two matrices Ab?

Comment: sorry I made a mistake in by b matrix but I just edited it

Comment: Yes and after multiplication you will get a non-null vector. So  $b$ is not in the null space of $A$.

Comment: so I got 0 2 4 so since Ab does not equal 0 b is not in the null space of A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $b \in \operatorname{Null} (A)$ if and only if $Ab =0$, so in this case we have
$$Ab = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\ 5 & 6 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} \neq \vec{0}$$
Hence $b \not \in \operatorname{Null}(A)$.

Comment: awesome that makes sense to me, thanks for your time